# adding 30 minutes to date

Tags: php, date, timestamp

So what I need to do is add 30 minutes to the following

```
date("Ymdhis");
```

I tried this

```
+strtotime("+30 minutes");
```

however it does not seem to like it. I wondering what the correct why to do this is.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+minutes+php

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your method of using `strtotime` should work.

```
<?php

echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime("now")) . "\n";
echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 minutes"));

?>
```

**Output**

```
2012/03/22 10:55:45
2012/03/22 11:25:45 // 30 minutes later
```

However your method of adding time probably isn't correct. The above will work to add 30 minutes to the current time. Suppose you want to add 30 minutes from a given time, `$t`, then use `strtotime`'s second parameter, which is used as a base for the calculation of relative dates.

```
date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 minutes", $t));
```

http://codepad.org/Z5yquF55

Answer (score 11):

I tested this code but it doesn't work for me:

```
 $t = date();  
 date("Y/m/d h:i:s", strtotime("+30 minutes", $t));
```

Here's my solution

```
 //This is where you put the date, but I use the current date for this example
 $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

 //Convert the variable date using strtotime and 30 minutes then format it again on the desired date format
 $add_min = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date . "+30 minutes"));
 echo  $date . "<br />"; //current date or whatever date you want to put in here
 echo  $add_min; //add 30 minutes
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like.

```
$Start = "12:00:00";
$Minutes = 30;

$To = date("H:i:s", strtotime($Start)+($Minutes*60));
```

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime()` accepts a second parameter which is its starting point.

If you have `date("Ymdhis", $somedate)` and wanted to add 30 minutes to it, you can do 
`date("Ymdhis", strtotime("+30 minutes", $someddate))`

Answer (score 2):

Use this function:

```
date("Ymdhis", strtotime("+30 minutes"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your entire code looks like, but:

```
date("Ymdhis");
```

is returning a string. So it doesn't make sense to add the result of

```
strtotime("+30 minutes");
```

(which is an integer) to that string.

You either want

```
strtotime("+30 minutes");
```

by itself, or

```
date("Ymdhis", strtotime("+30 minutes"));
```

to get the formatted string.

Comment: Note that in all of these answers, you are getting GMT (or UTC or whatever you want to call it) time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `date("Ymdhis", strtotime("+30 minutes"));`? This will represent the date that is 30 minutes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php
print date("Y-m-d h:i:s", (time() + (60*30)) );
?>
```